# Fourier Series of $f(x)$ involving $\cos$ and $\sin$ components

Tags: fourier-series

How do I find the real Fourier series of $f(x)=\cos(\frac{x}{2})+ 0.1\sin(5x)$, where the function is periodic defined between $-\pi$ and $\pi$?

Comment: what do you mean by real fourier series?

Comment: Thats the way the question was written. It said " Show that the real fourier series of f(x) is given by: f(x)=2/pi + 0.1sin(5x) + Sum4(-1)^n / (1-4n^2)pi cos(nx)